# Heroku- was working before computer restarted, now can't push to remote repository- access denied

Tags: git, heroku

My heroku/git set up was working perfectly until I restarted my computer. Now when I attempt to push any change to the remote repository I get the following error.

```
  !  Your key with fingerprint ..... is not authorized to access .....

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I tried looking at heroku keys:add but that didn't seem to make any difference.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a problem with your ssh keys. Check your ~/.ssh directory for the keys and ensure that they match up with what you have on Heroku.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys this link taks about setting up your keys for use with their system.

Hopefully that helps :)

Comment: Thanks! How can I tell which key uses which fingerprint? When I run heroku keys I get 4 entries, 2 of which are git and 2 are my email address...

Comment: If you check under https://dashboard.heroku.com/account, the ssh key section should have the key you linked to your account. You can open up the different files in your favorite text editor and check their contents to make sure one matches. The proper key will be "public" and have the .pub extension. You can always delete or add a key to heroku and test if that resolves it.

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me. I deleted all the keys from the account and started fresh, but no dice. Even generated a new key, added it and it still won't work. I don't get it, it was working just an hour ago...

Comment: No problem :). Typically from my experience its best to use one pub/private key pair instead of making a separate one for heroku. Is one of your keys for github? If so try pushing to github and see if that works still. If so, use that same key on heroku and try pushing to heroku. That shoud narrow down the problem.

Comment: So one is for Git and I just tested and it works fine. I tried removing all Heroku keys and adding the git one, but I get the same error. I have a github_rsa, id_rsa and id_rsa_heroku. None seem to work.

Comment: Hmm...this is really odd. Try removing and reinstalling the heroku toolbelt. The removal commands are: rm -rf /usr/local/heroku
rm -rf /usr/bin/heroku

Comment: This is really odd, did you make sure to completely remove your key? Delete it from heroku, use the "ssh-add -d filename" command to remove it from your ssh agent, then finally delete the files, or rename them with a .bak extension or something. Then generate a new key using  ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa_heroku, ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_heroku and add it to heroku.

Answer (score 0):

http://tmtk75.github.io/2012/11/22/your_key_with_fingerprint_..._is_not_authorized_to_access_..._on_heroku.html?utm_expid=58395966-2&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F

This worked for me. Not sure why but at least it worked!